# does svg support referencing path's?

Tags: svg, optimization, vector-graphics

I have repeating patterns in my vector, i was wondering if svg supports referencing the same path and use it on different position just to reduce size of svg.

something like

```
<path name="repeating_path" d="..."/>
<path ref="repeating_path" transform="translate(10 10)"/>
```

Comment: Try the [<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element.

Comment: or [`<pattern>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern).